# Why full fence allows mix store-load operation

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

What is idea to allow mixing Store with Load procedure in `Full fence`? According to my understanding it is still not safe in case I load the same variable I store to:

```
int a=0;
...
a=2;
full_fence;
print(a)
```

According to my understanding it is possible `0` to be printed? What is idea to leave such gap?

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ and C#?

Comment: Just studying this problem in both languages

Comment: Ok.  But if the question doesn't explicitly have anything to do with a language (i.e. it could just as easily have been Rust + Go), then please don't tag it as such :/